# ListView not saving items on next position, keeps replacing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a simple "Notes" app but when the user tries to save a new note it replaces the current note. Kindly help me out & tell me where the issue is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.sibi.notes",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("");

    list.add("Add a new note");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            long addNote = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(1);

            if (id == addNote){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
     });
     String text = sharedPreferences.getString("Note","");

     if(text != ""){
       list.add(text);
     }

}
```

Comment: please clear your problem, when you add note on your list just call adapter.notifydatasetchange() for updating list.

Comment: Post complete code where you are adding the new note.

Answer (score 0):

When the data of your adapter is changed use adapter.notifyDatasetchanged() or adapter.notifyItemInserted(position) or adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) or ... or notifyAll() (in your activity).If your data is huge use notifyItemXX(s) according to your action. If this is not a solution for you , you could again set your adapter with the changed data(here your changed list)